# Iterating over a JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter

How do I grab - or more specifically, iterate over - the contents of a JSON user_timeline object in PHP? I have it retrieved, I'm just trying to access the fields in the object. All of the other tutorials/answers don't apply to the new 1.1 API. Here's where I am:

```
    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
    $getfield = '?screen_name=testyMcTesterton';
    $requestMethod = 'GET';

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you posted the contents of the object itself it would help, but can you not just `json_decode($obj)`? From that do something like:

```
$new = json_decode($obj);
$data = $new->data; // (this would access Object->data->*)
```

That's how a JSON array is accessed, though I don't actually know how the Twitter user_timeline object looks so I can't tell you exactly how to access the elements you want specifically.